# How can I download application from app store through my android application?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to download application from app store (Google Play, Amazon App Store) through my application. I have searched to much regarding this but not getting proper method or code to implement it.

But I have to implement it for Amazon app store, please guide me how to implement for Amazon app store.

Please help me how can I implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a link to a URL on the app store. When you open the link, it will redirect to the store (well it did in my case, anyways!)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, have you implement it ?

Comment: The only way I could do it is just open the web browser and go to the app store URL. I have and it is easy enough to do